# VGA compatible controller (Intel and Nvidia)

Tags: debian, vga, controller

I need to know the bus address of my video controller to fix a problem about the brightness keybinding on Debian Wheezy.

I did **`lspci | grep VGA`**

and the result is:

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation
>   Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
>
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce
>   GT 520MX] (rev a1)

My question is which address from ***00:02.0*** and ***01:00.0*** I have to take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to guess and say you have an Asus laptop where the fn key is required to adjust brightness. Secondly, I'm going to guess that instead of the "flicker" problem, you can't get the brightness to adjust at all.

If any of the above is true please proceed. Otherwise you might fill in some more info such as what you're planning to doing with the bus id of your gpu and hdmi audio contoller.

Possible solution:

- open /etc/X11/xorg.conf
- under “Device” add

  **Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"**
- reboot

**EDIT I can't comment due to low privileges on this SE so I'll have to respond up here.**
You have two graphics cards.The first bus ID (00:02.0) is the graphics card that is built directly in the mother board. The second one (01:00.0) is your HDMI out cable for the nvidia card and (depending on the model of ASUS) is likely the one that is controlling your laptop's internal monitor. Whatever you're trying to do, you should probably do it to the second bus id 01:00.0.

Comment: Yes I have an Asus, but I don't have any "flicker" problem. I'm going just to understand why the command `xdev` don't show any signal from Fn+F5 and Fn+F6 although the keys work well.

Comment: How did you know it was HDMI?